# Creating new java processes like sub jvm

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I want to implement a java application which starts new spring application contexts.

The question is: is there a way give memory size for each context without creating new JVMs?

I am asking this because , first, I thought I can create an engine which is responsible of creating new application contexts from given files, like:

```
public void createContext(String path){
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext_IBN.xml");
}
```

But the case in here is, I think, I can not know which context consumes how much memory/resource etc, so if one of the process consumes more resource then it should, all the processes will be effected...

After that, I looked for information about if there is a way to create sub JVM s, like giving each process -Xmx etc.

So finally , I am here:) Thank you for your helpful responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a new process on your os, the sole way of creating a new process in java is the [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).